# php preg_match_all function parameters in php file of one function

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to find `functionName('MATCH_1') ;`, `functionName( "MATCH2");` and ... `functionName ('MATCH_X') ;` and extract `MATCH_XXX` by the following text.

The text:
Some text functionName('MATCH_1'); and other text functionName( "MATCH_2") ; and many another text.

Or many more in next line functionName( 'MATCH_X'); ... more text.

I want to get `MATCH_1`, `MATCH2` and `MATCH_X`

My try:

```
<?php
preg_match_all('#functionName\s*\(\s*(\'|")(.*)(\'|")\s*\)\s*;#im', $content,$matches);
```

But my RegEx does not make what I want.
Can you please explain me, as the RegEx must look like. And why he works like that.

regards
raiserle

Comment: Can you provide `$content` in a reproducible format? Without an `^` or `$` the `m` modifier is useless.

Comment: Replace `.*` with `.*?` or maybe even `[^"\']*`

Comment: @chris85: Why is the ``m`` useless?

Comment: @raiserle The `m` modifies how the `^` and `$` interact with a line or string. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php `If there are...no occurrences of ^ or $ in a pattern, setting this modifier has no effect.`

Comment: @chris85:Thank you. My fault - I've read on other page, the ``m`` - modifier is for multi lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$content = "The text: Some text functionName('MATCH_1'); and other text functionName( \"MATCH_2\") ; and many another text. Or many more in next line functionName( 'MATCH_X'); ... more text.";

preg_match_all('#functionName\s*\(\s*(\'|")(.*?)(\'|")\s*\)\s*;#im', $content,$matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

and then you should have what you want in `$matches[2]`.

what i changed is i added the `?` after the `.*` part of the regex, making it non-greedy (matching the shortest possible string instead of the longest match). This does make it less performant. See: [here](http://regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) for an explanation of why and more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you. ``?`` after ``.*`` works exactly. The link is perfect.
``MATCH_1');?>functionName('MATCH2`` is now correct.